# QGIS print layout: Dynamic text with attributes from different layers with different geometry

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, atlas

I have made a print layout containing a map and 2 different vector layers. 1 polygon and 1 point layer.

I have used til polygon layer to control my atlas function.

The polygons are fields and the points are samples of the soils within the polygon. I have 51 fields each containing a number of points.

Can I make a dynamic text containing the average value of a colomn from the point layer's attribute table? Only showing the average number of the field, that the layout shows.

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression to calculate the mean value of the field `value` from layer `points`, but only for points features overlapping the current atlas feature:

```
array_mean (overlay_intersects ('points',"value"))
```

*only points in the current field/atlas feature are considered, points in other fields (here e.g. 7 and 14) are ignored:*
[image]

Comment: That was very helpfull. There is a small difference from the calculatet number in qgis to the real number. But I think it happens because the attributtabel is rounding decimals to the field. Note to myself, i can´t you layername, i have to click on maplayer and at the layer from there. I can´t just write rt_2022, which is my layer name.

Comment: For rounding errors, check, check field length. If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it (hit the checkmark next to it)

Comment: Where is the check field length?

Comment: See here, but go to the tab fields: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470634/88814 when you create a new field, you can define length and decimal precision of a decimal field. Precision 2 means that 2.543 is rounded to. 2 digits: 2.54

Comment: Allright.
I have made this where til polygonlayerlabel is rule based and should show the averagenumber of the points within the field (RT Gns:). ('Rt Gns:' ||  '\n'  || round(array_mean(overlay_intersects('Terra_Agro_jordpr_ver_2023_8344da87_94a0_45be_abd1_b251a4dafee1',"Rt")),2)
But the average number is not 5,78 bur closer to 6,2. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k29sK.png

Comment: So obviously, there are some more numbers included in the calculation. Without seeing the data/project its impossible to see what's going wrong. For testing puropose: does `array_mean(array( ...))` and filling `...` with comma separated list of the numbers you have (fill them in manually) produce the correct result?

Comment: Here are the values of the point within a polygon. If I use the basic statistics tool, the mean number is correct.  (5,8-6,3-6-5,8-5,9-6-6,2-6-6,1-6,2-6) But not when i use this: round(array_sum(overlay_intersects('Terra_Agro_jordpr_ver_2023_8344da87_94a0_45be_abd1_b251a4dafee1', "Rt")) / array_length(overlay_intersects('Terra_Agro_jordpr_ver_2023_8344da87_94a0_45be_abd1_b251a4dafee1', "Rt")), 2)

Comment: Try array_mean(array( ...)) and filling ... with comma separated list of the numbers you have (fi. What is the result? Without overlay function!

Comment: When I do that i get a value of 6.02727 etc, and that is correct.

Comment: Ok, so the problem ist with overlay. Without seeing your project it's difficult to say what goes wrong, would be pure speculation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149843/discussion-between-jonas-and-babel).